# getMap() throws an NullPointerException for some devices

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to inflate a MapFragment within my application but recently, it has started throwing `NullPointerException` on some devices, mostly Samsung devices. My code in my activity is

```
if (map == null) {
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

And in my XML I define the fragment with

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Does anyone have any reasons why this might be crashing on some devices but not others?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is Android fault. In Android Marshmallow 6.0 and higher you need to make requesting for permission, adding it in manifest is not enough.

Comment: I added those check when the app is first launched and it seems to work find on my test device (Moto X Pure with 6.0). In the analytics it says it is happening on 5.1 devices and one of my users called me saying they have a older Samsung device (I'm assuming an S4)